# Replacing Text with Special Characters in sed - Whole Word Only

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to use the sed editor to read a file and replace all
occurrences of the string `XYZ$` with `xyz$`.  I only want to do this if `XYZ$`
is a whole word, not if it is embedded in another string.

I tried the following, which did not work:

```
sed -c -i "s/\bXYZ\$\b/xyz\$/g" file1.txt
```

Perhaps `\$` is not being interpreted as a literal dollar sign, possibly because it is inside a pair of `\b` (used to denote a word boundary). Any suggestions?

Comment: The text to be replaced could be anywhere on a line.  So I would like to replace the line: 123 XYZ$ 456 with the line: 123 xyz$ 456   So I would like to use the word boundary option.

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using?  While GNU `sed` supports `\b`, not all versions of `sed` do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match `\b` after `$` since that is not considered a word character.

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i 's/\bXYZ\$/xyz$/g' file
```

If you want to make sure there is always a non word character after `$` then use:

```
sed -ir 's/\bXYZ\$([^[:alnum:]]|$)/xyz$\1/g' file
```

Comment: Is `\\$` needed to escape `$`? What about `XYZ$ABC`?

Comment: No `\\$` is not needed in single quotes.

Comment: So it's needed in double quotes as OP using it.

Comment: Double quotes is not really needed here, better to use single quote to avoid accidental shell expansion.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
"s/\bXYZ\b\$ /xyz\$ /g"
```

A word character is [a-zA-Z0-9_], so a $ will never match inside a boundary (\b).

So end your boundary, check to ensure $ is the next character, followed by a space.

Inputs:

```
This xyz$ is unchanged.
This XYZ$is unchanged
This XYZ$ is changed.
```

Outputs:

```
This xyz$ is unchanged.
This XYZ$is unchanged
This xyz$ is changed.
```

Comment: what about if `XYZ$` is in the end of the line/string?